# What happened when a restarted actor be created by another actor using context.actorOf?

Tags: scala, akka

```
package actor.faulttolerance

import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Restart
import akka.actor._
import akka.event.LoggingReceive

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
/**
  * Created by lc on 2015/11/28.
  */
object CounterService {

  case class Increment(n: Int)

  case object GetCurrentCount

  case class CurrentCount(key: String, value: Long)

  case class ServiceUnavailable(msg: String) extends RuntimeException

  private case object Reconnect

}

class CounterService extends Actor {

  import Counter._
  import CounterService._
  import Storage._

  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 3, withinTimeRange = 5 seconds) {
    case _: StorageException => Restart
  }
  val key = self.path.name
  var storage: Option[ActorRef] = None
  var counter: Option[ActorRef] = None
  var backlog = IndexedSeq.empty[(ActorRef, Any)]
  val MaxBacklog = 10000


  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    initStorage()
  }

  /**
    * *
    * The child storage is restarted in case of failure, but after 3 restarts,
    * and still failing it will be stopped. Better to back-off than continuously
    * failing. When it has been stopped we will schedule a Reconnect after a delay
    * Watch the child so we receive Terminated message when it has been terminated
    */
  def initStorage(): Unit = {
    storage = Some(context.watch(context.actorOf(Props[Storage], name = "storage")))
    counter foreach {
      _ ! UseStorage(storage)
    }
    storage.get ! Get(key)
  }

  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case Entry(k, v) if k == key && counter == None =>
      // Reply from Storage of the initial value, now we can create the Counter
      val c = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[Counter], key, v))
      counter = Some(c)
      // Tell the counter to use current storage
      c ! UseStorage(storage)
      // and send the buffered backlog to the counter
      for ((replyTo, msg) <- backlog) c.tell(msg, sender = replyTo)
      backlog = IndexedSeq.empty
    case msg@Increment(n) => forwardOrPlaceInBacklog(msg)
    case msg@GetCurrentCount => forwardOrPlaceInBacklog(msg)
    case Terminated(actorRef) if Some(actorRef) == storage =>
      // After 3 restarts the storage child is stopped.
      // We receive Terminated because we watch the child, see initStorage.
      storage = None
      // Tell the counter that there is no storage for the moment
      counter foreach {
        _ ! UseStorage(None)
      }
      // Try to re-establish storage after while
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 seconds, self, Reconnect)
    case Reconnect =>
      // Re-establish storage after the scheduled delay
      initStorage()
  }


  def forwardOrPlaceInBacklog(msg: Any) {

    // We need the initial value from storage before we can start delegate to
    // the counter. Before that we place the messages in a backlog, to be sent
    // to the counter when it is initialized.
    counter match {
      case Some(c) => c forward msg
      case None =>
        if (backlog.size >= MaxBacklog)
          throw new ServiceUnavailable(
            "CounterService not available, lack of initial value")
        backlog :+= (sender() -> msg)
    }
  }

}
```

The code is from akka doc, if child actor storage failed 3 times, the supervisor actor CounterService will issue a Restart. During storage actor restarting, when stoped, CounterService actor will watch storage actor's death, get the Terminated message, set it's storage ref to None, and reconnect after 10 seconds. In reconnecting, CounterService actor will create a new storage actor using: `storage = Some(context.watch(context.actorOf(Props[Storage], name = "storage")))`.

From akka doc I know that:

1. Actor restarting will create a new actor instance and just swap it.
2. `context.actorOf` will create a new actor ref.

So will storage actor be created once by restarting and again by CounterService actor's `context.actorOf`? Will the actor created by restarting be forgotten?
Or when `contex.actorOf` see that the storage actor has been restarted and instance swapped, it just use the new one and not always creating a new one? I look the doc but didn't find the clue.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer by reading akka doc carefully.

There are limits set on the restart frequency. In the above code, it's max retries 3 times in 5 seconds. The child actor is stopped if the limit is exceeded.
So the first 3 times storage actor failed, the actor restarted immediately. It's supervisor, CounterService would do nothing. After 3 times retried or 5 seconds passed, storage actor is stoped and CounterService  receives storage actor Terminated message and rennect in 10 seconds.

so :
1. when contex.actorOf see that the storage actor has been restarted and instance swaped, it just use the new one not always creating a new one?
when storage actor restarted, CounterService actor won't know.
2. will the actor created by restarting be forgotten?
 it will be stoped after retry limits.